# Laravel validation for unique in table within a few rows?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to add data to a table named **students**.

Before entering I need to validate student roll no. inserted through form. This roll number should be unique in particular class.

How will I validate this uniqueness using Laravel validation rules?

**students** table contains following columns:

*ID, STUDNAME, STUDCLASS, ROLLNO, ADMINNO*

where field named *STUDCLASS* is class id.

So this *ROLLNO* field should be unique in rows with same *STUDCLASS* value.

How will I do this validation in Laravel?

Comment: Why have you got both laravel-4 and laravel-5 tags? Which version are you using?

Comment: I need to tag minimum 4 areas. So I selected Laravel 4, Laravel- 5 , Laravel and PHP. Else how will I post with only one tag.??

Comment: What are you on about? Why do you need a minimum of 4 tags? Laravel-4 indicates you are using Laravel version 4, Laravel-5 indicates you are using Laravel version 5. You can't be using both, I've removed them both until you clarify what version you are using.

Comment: I am using Laravel 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the validator as follows . the condition will be added as where clause where STUDCLASS = Input::get('studclass')

```
      $validator = Validator::make(array(
                    'roll_number' => Input::get('roll_number'),

                        ), array(                        
                    'roll_number' => 'required|unique:tbl_students,roll_number,NULL,id,STUDCLASS,'.Input::get('studclass')
        ));



       if ($validator->fails()) {

           echo  $validator->messages()->first();

        }
```

Comment: This is what I added 'studrollno'=>'required|numeric|unique:tbl_students,studrollno,studcls'.$clsid, . But it is not working

Comment: you forgot the null in between. the conditions work in sucha manner . unique:table,column,except,idColumn

Comment: I added NULL like this...'studrollno' => 'required|unique:tbl_students,studrollno, NULL, studcls,'.$clsid, .. But I am getting an error, 'Undefined offset: 1', Can you please tell me, what is the reason??

Comment: 'studrollno' => 'required|unique:tbl_students,studrollno, NULL, id, studcls,'.$clsid  ..... add the id field in between. id is the primary key of the table.

Comment: I changed as your reply. 'studrollno' => 'required|unique:wys_students,studrollno, NULL, id, studcls,'.$clsid,... But I am getting error.. Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `tbl_students` where `studrollno` = 1 and ` id` <> NULL and ` studcls` = 2)

Comment: is your primary key column name  'id' or 'ID'.. change it according to the database

Comment: Following is migration file for this table   Schema::create('tbl_students',function(Blueprint $table) 
  {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->string('studname');
      $table->string('studadno');
      $table->string('studrollno');
      $table->string('studcls');
   $table->timestamps();
     });

Comment: here is the probelm check : select count(*) as aggregate from tbl_students where studrollno = 1 and ` id` <> NULL and ` studcls` = 2  .. the ` id` as a space before id. it should be `id` and not ` id`.

Comment: It is working.... Thank you. .. Thanks a lot ... sorry for wasting your precious time...